# Horizontal UIScrollview always bouncing back, even after setting contenSize bigger - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have implemented a horizontal `UIScrollview` (adding buttons into it) but it always bounces back to original position after I scroll it. Searched a lot but the answers were of no luck as yet.

This is the scroll view below, of the same width as screen,

[image: ScrollView]

And this is the view inside it, which is of 800+ width,

[image: view inside scrollview]

Also in me class, I have implemented the following code:

`_imageEffectsScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(832, 80);`

In fact it just now scrolls a little bit, instead of bouncing back ( like before ):
[image]

Please help, how can I make it scroll properly. Thanks!

Comment: check the auto layout constraints between scrollView, container view , and buttons. I saw -432 trailing constraint in your snapshot.

Comment: Yes. I removed it but now the scrollview bounces back. with that constraint atleast it moves a little (As shown in the last snapshot

Comment: You should change it to 0, so scrollView contentSize can be set by container view size

Comment: Wow! That worked magically! Thanks @SolaWing , but can you please elaborate why it worked? Pleasee..

Comment: In autoLayout, UIScrollView's contentSize is determined by it's contentView. set the contentSize in code will have no effect, cause AutoLayout overwrite it. Thus When you contentView's leading and trailing equal to scrollView, the scrollView's content width will be set to contentView's width. And when you set incorrectly, scrollView will have wrong content Size.

Comment: Thanks @SolaWing! If you could just post your solution as an answer, then I can mark it correct! Thanks again